# checkbox multiple value color div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have three checkboxes
if at least one value is checked, the colour of div 'adi' changes in red, but if i check them all and i uncheck one of them, the colour returns to normal.
I Want this to Happen only after i will have already unchecked all the three values

```js
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        $('.adi').addClass("redBackground"); 
    }else{
        $('.adi').removeClass("redBackground");  
    }
});
```

```css
.redBackground{
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><input type='checkbox' name='groupid' value='1'>1</div>
<div><input type='checkbox' name='groupid' value='2'>2</div>
<div><input type='checkbox' name='groupid' value='3'>3</div>

<div class="adi">

asdasdas
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate, the code here should help you determine if none are checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11787455/warn-user-if-all-checkboxes-are-unchecked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate the length of checked inputs with `$chb.filter(":checked").length` and *boolean*ize using `> 0` for the `.toggleClass("className", boolean)` to do the job.

```js
var $chb =  $("input[name='groupid']");

$chb.on("change", function(){
  $('.adi').toggleClass("redBackground", $chb.filter(":checked").length > 0 ); 
});
```

```css
.redBackground{
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><input type='checkbox' name='groupid' value='1'>1</div>
<div><input type='checkbox' name='groupid' value='2'>2</div>
<div><input type='checkbox' name='groupid' value='3'>3</div>

<div class="adi">

asdasdas
</div>
```

Comment: Good solution. It can be shortened to var $chb  = $("input[name='groupid']");

$chb.change(function(){
  $('.adi').toggleClass("redBackground", !!$chb.filter(":checked").length); 
});

Comment: Its because in .toggleClass method you cant just use truthy/falsy value (like 0/1), but only Boolean value - true/false.

Comment: @WaldemarIce you're totally right :) Thanks for the note

Comment: @WaldemarIce I see. There were absolutely no need to create a copy - answer with functional - non-functional examples from **this answer** cause it adds no additional value to this one.

Comment: PS: Look down the page for my (veeery:) original/breakneck solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try whit this:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){    
    var checked_count = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
    if (checked_count>0) {
            $('.adi').addClass("redBackground"); 
    }else{
            $('.adi').removeClass("redBackground");  
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the else part of your if you must check before if the number of checked checkboxes is zero and then you may remove the class:

```js
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
  if($(this).is(":checked")){
    $('.adi').addClass("redBackground");
  } else {
    if ($("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length == 0) {
      $('.adi').removeClass("redBackground");
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.redBackground{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div><input type='checkbox' name='groupid' value='1'>1</div>
<div><input type='checkbox' name='groupid' value='2'>2</div>
<div><input type='checkbox' name='groupid' value='3'>3</div>

<div class="adi">

    asdasdas
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){

     $(".adi").toggleClass("redBackground", $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length > 0)

    })

})
```

**Final code :**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
        
        $(".adi").toggleClass("redBackground", $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length > 0)
        
        
    })
    
})
```

```css
.redBackground{
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div><input type='checkbox' name='groupid' value='1'>1</div>
<div><input type='checkbox' name='groupid' value='2'>2</div>
<div><input type='checkbox' name='groupid' value='3'>3</div>
<div class="adi">
asdasdas
</div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add one if statement to your js code:

```js
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        $('.adi').addClass("redBackground"); 
    }else{
        if (!$("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length)
            $('.adi').removeClass("redBackground");  
    }
});
```

```css
.redBackground{
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><input type='checkbox' name='groupid' value='1'>1</div>
<div><input type='checkbox' name='groupid' value='2'>2</div>
<div><input type='checkbox' name='groupid' value='3'>3</div>

<div class="adi">

asdasdas
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fully functional, but little bit breakneck code...

```js
$(function () {
  var chLst   = [],
      $notice = $("#notice"),
      $chBx   = $notice.next().children();
  $chBx.change(function () {
    chLst[$chBx.index(this)] = !chLst[$chBx.index(this)];
    if (chLst.reduce((f,n)=>f||n) ^ $notice.is(".green")) $notice.toggleClass("green");
  });
});
```

```css
#notice h1 { text-align:center }
.green     { color:green       }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="notice">
  <h1>SOME NOTIFICATION</h1>
</div>
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="value" value="1"> Checkbox 1<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="value" value="2"> Checkbox 2<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="value" value="3"> Checkbox 3<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="value" value="4"> Checkbox 4<br>
</form>
```